# Why do nonlinearities in deep neural nets give rise to very high derivatives?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, nonlinearity

In the book "Deep Learning" by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville, I do not understand the following statement about why nonlinearities in deep neural nets give rise to very high derivatives:

> The objective function for highly nonlinear deep neural networks or for
>   recurrent neural networks often contains sharp nonlinearities in parameter space resulting
>   from the multiplication of several parameters. These nonlinearities give rise to very
>   high derivatives in some places. When the parameters get close to such a cliff region, a
>   gradient descent update can catapult the parameters very far, possibly losing most of the
>   optimization work that has been done.

Comment: Isn't this related to the exploding gradient problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Digio's comment, this is a description of the *exploding gradient problem*. If you are familiar with Newton's method from calculus, we can look at a simple example in the single variable case. Updates are proportional to the value of the derivative of the function: $x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}$ If the value of the derivative at $x_{n}$ is huge, $\Delta x = x_{n+1} - x_{n}$ may diverge to infinity - i.e., *explode*. Here is an image of this same phenomenon occurring with a multivariate function:

[image: Update trajectory demonstrating the exploding gradient problem]

The source for the above image is "Understanding the exploding gradient problem" by Pascano, Mikolov, and Bengio (2012) : https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Understanding-the-exploding-gradient-problem-Pascanu-Mikolov/728d814b92a9d2c6118159bb7d9a4b3dc5eeaaeb

I highly recommend reading the article - it is quite informative and will provide you with a deeper understanding of this problem.